# NSLog what I assume is an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to log what I assume is an object called message, but what I get is a memory address which looks something like `<Message: 0x5cy4e5db90p0>`. I've mostly worked in Node so I was hoping NSLog would return something like `{prop: value, prop: value}` because I'm trying to figure out what properties message has. I'm also assuming message is an object because in the rest of the code, message has properties like createdOn and time.

```
- (void)messageUpdates:(Message*) message{ 
    NSlog(@"%@ obj", message)  
}
```

I deleted most of the code but essentially I want to see what is being passed into this function. Is there a way to see the properties of message instead of what I'm currently receiving? Thank you!

Comment: Implement a useful `description` method in your `Message` class.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for pointing me to that resource. I was able to use breakpoints and see the properties of the objects I was looking at. I'll look adding a description method... thanks again!